# Regex to identify lines in a text with just numbers or single characters

Tags: python, regex, string, pattern-matching

Folks,

I have a use-case which I know can be solved by traditional string methods in Python. I am looking for more regex'ing way to solve it.

**Use-case:**

> Given a text from a file, I want to remove all such lines which
>   contains either
>
> - Only single numbers (may or may not be in parenthesis) such as 29, [29], (29), {29}
> - Only single character (may or may not be in parenthesis) such as m, [m], (m), {m}
> - Only just empty lines

**Python way (I know of):**

> - Strip out the whitespace if any from the ends
> - Strip out the parenthesis (if any)
> - For number: Check if the string is a digit using str.isdigit()
> - For character, just check length of this string equal to 1

**Example:**

```
hello world...
again hello world...

29 

..
[a]
bye bye...
see you..
```

**Expected Output:**

```
hello world...
again hello world...
..
bye bye...
see you..
```

I want to understand how to perform these steps using a single regex (if possible).

Thanks!

Comment: If you mark it as close, please care to comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
^[({\[]?(?:\d+|[a-z])?[)}\]]?\s*$[\n\r]
```

Which would be replaced by an empty string, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/QL7xGU/2).
When starting to learn regular expressions, turn the "*verbose*" mode on as often as possible.

---

In this case

```
^         # the start of a line in multiline mode (m flag)
[({\[]?   # a character class ([...]) of (,{ or [ zero or 1 times
(?:       # opening of a non-capturing class
    \d+   # multiple digits
|         # or
    [a-z] # a,b,c,...z
)?        # zero or 1 times
[)}\]]?   # one of ), } or ], zero or 1 times
\s*       # whitespaces, eventually
$         # end of the line
[\n\r]    # newline characters
```

For more information, see [**Learning regular expressions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions) or [**Mastering Regular Expressions**](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596002893.do).